# C# How to determine a status of a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, timer

I have a tray app that starts ( Form 1 ) and shows on right click a "Login" menu strip item.
On click, I setup a Form 2, asking for user and pass.
On a successful authentication, I'd like to close Form 2 and continue with Form 1 ( ie. I would like to start a timer ).

I was thinking of just setting up a timer which would check the Form 2 status ( basically a getter function inside Form 2 ).
Still, I think there has to be an easier way than having something tick.

Comment: You should name your forms.  (eg, `MainForm` and `LoginForm`)

Comment: Why use a timer? Are buttons considered "ugly" or "unsightly" now or something?

Comment: @SLaks and @Cody - you guys sure know how NOT to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need a timer or any thing for that just show the form as a [Modal Dialogue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) and return to main form when closed.

Comment: How would I go about setting the DialogResult to OK in case of a successful authentification ?

Comment: you can use a button on the form to set the DilogueResult property look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should show the login form using the [`ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

This method shows a modal dialog which will prevent the user from interacting with the rest of your application until the dialog is closed.

You should then perform authentication in the login form's button click handler, and close the form when it's successful.